# About a subgroup $G\subset \mathbb R$ with $G\cap (-1,1)=\{0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a non-trivial subgroup of $(\mathbb R, +)$ such that $G\cap
>  (-1,1)=\{0\}$. Prove that $G=r\mathbb Z$ for some $r\ge 1$.

I showed that $G $ cannot contain non-isolated points (because if any neighborhood (in $\mathbb R$ of a point $x\in G$ has other points in $G$, then there is a point $x\ne y\in G$ within distance $1/4$ of $x$, and then either of the two elements of $G$ $x-y$ or $y-x$ lies in $(-1,1)\setminus \{0\}$, a contradiction.)

I can also show that $G=r\mathbb Z$, where $r=\inf \{x\in G: x> 0\}$ under the assumption $r\in G$. It is clear that $r\mathbb Z\subseteq G$. To see that $G\subseteq r\mathbb Z$, note that if $z\notin r\mathbb Z$, then $z\in (rk,(k+1)r) $ for $k\in \mathbb Z$, and if $z\in G$, then either $z-rk\in G$, a contradiction. So $z\notin G$.

But I have problems in showing that $r\in G$. Obviously I must use that $r$ is the infimum. This means that for any $\epsilon > 0,$ $r+\epsilon $ is not a lower bound, i.e., there are elements of $G$ to the left of $r+\epsilon$. I tried assuming that $r\notin G$ but I don't see what it contradicts to. However I feel there must be some trivial solution to this...

Comment: You know that $G$ is disconnected, so the infimum is just the minimum

Comment: @KennyLau How can I use this?

Comment: Another way to do this would be to take $ x \in G$ and look at the quotient of $\mathbb{R}/ \langle x \rangle$. This is just $S^1$ so is compact. Then the map given by the composition $G \to \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ shows that the image of $G$ in the quotient is discrete. This approach generalizes to $\mathbb{R}^n$ more readily

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ an integer  such that $¸[0,n]\cap G=C$ is not empty, $C$ is finite otherwise it has an accumulation point, and for every real number $e$, there exists $c_1,c_2\in C$ such that $|c_1-c_2|<e$ in particular you can take $e=r$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r=\inf G \cap (0,\infty )$. Then $1 \leq r <\infty $. Let $g_k \in G$ and $g_k$ decrease to $r$. Suppose $G \cap (rn,r(n+1))$ is non-empty for some positive integer $n$.  Pick $g$ in this set and note that $g-nr =\lim (g-ng_k)$. But $g-nr \in (0,r)$ and $g-ng_k \in (0,r)$ for $k$ sufficiently large so we have an element of $G$ on $(0,r)$ which is a contradiction. Hence $G \cap (rn,r(n+1))$ is empty for each $n$. This implies that $G \cap (0,\infty ) =\{r,2r,3r,...\}$. Since $G$ is a subgroup we get $G \cap (-\infty ,\infty ) =\{0,r,-r,2r,-2r,3r,-3r,...\}$.